# method save as as object workbook failed

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save my workbook in one location file but then face an

> error run time error '1004'

where the method save as is failed. below is my code

```
Sub SaveInvoice()
Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = "\\Data\2022\FFTM\021.FFTM Declaration Data\1. Classes\" & Sheets("Marks").Range("G10") & "\" & Sheets("Marks").Range("C2") & "\" & Sheets("Marks").Range("F12") & "_" & Sheets("Marks").Range("K12") & "_" & Sheets("Marks").Range("E2") & "_" & Sheets("Marks").Range("L7") & ".xls"

'create invoice in XLSX format
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\Data\2022\FFTM\021.FFTM Declaration Data\1. Classes\" & Sheets("Marks").Range("G10") & "\" & Sheets("Marks").Range("C2") & "\" & Sheets("Marks").Range("F12") & "_" & Sheets("Marks").Range("K12") & "_" & Sheets("Marks").Range("E2") & "_" & Sheets("Marks").Range("L7") & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

'ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Cells(83, 17) = Application.UserName

MsgBox "Saving Complete! Have a nice day~"

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are going to save it as an XLS then you need to use the right file type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat - the one you have is for XLSM files.

Comment: i've used xlsx format **xlOpenXMLWorkbook** but it still highlights the same line when im debug **activeworkbook.save as \\path** @braX

Comment: Store the result of the really long line into a variable before you try to use it - then check it by putting a breakpoint on that line. Maybe the path is wrong. There could be a lot of possible problems but since we don't know the values in any of those cells it's impossible to know. Does is exactly match `MyFile`? What is the exact value of `MyFile` ?

Comment: Per earlier comment you should be using `xlExcel8` as the file format for `.xls` files.